# Find the minimum temperature at which the reaction will become spontaneous

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

This question came in my entrance exam and I think 273 K should be the answer because the reaction is already spontaneous. I just want to know if I've attempted it correctly.

> For a certain reaction $ΔG^\circ = \pu{-45 kJ mol-1}$ and $ΔH^\circ = \pu{-90 kJ mol-1}$ at $\pu{0 °C}$. What is the minimum temperature at which the reaction will become spontaneous, assuming that $ΔH^\circ$ and $ΔS^\circ$ are independent of temperature?
>
> (**a**) $\pu{273 K}$
> (**b**) $\pu{298 K}$
> (**c**) $\pu{546 K}$
> (**d**) $\pu{596 K}$

Answer (score 2):

You are only partially correct: negative Gibbs free energy at $\pu{273 K}$ is a sign of a spontaneous reaction.
However, the question asks *when* the reaction will become spontaneous and not to select the minimal temperature value from the multiple choices list which corresponds to the spontaneous process.

So, you were supposed to find the equilibrium temperature, e.g. when $ΔG = 0$. 
You have correctly started with the equation for the free Gibbs energy:

$$ΔG = ΔH - TΔS = 0  \quad\implies\quad T_\mathrm{eq} = \frac{ΔH}{ΔS}$$

Unknown entropy change $ΔS$ can be determined from the Gibbs free energy $ΔG_1$ at initial temperature $T_1$:

$$ΔS = \frac{ΔH - ΔG_1}{T_1}$$

Finally,

$$T_\mathrm{eq} = \frac{ΔH}{ΔS} = \frac{ΔH}{ΔH - ΔG_1}T_1 = \frac{\pu{-90 kJ mol-1}}{\pu{-90 kJ mol-1}-(\pu{-45 kJ mol-1})}\cdot\pu{273 K} = \pu{546 K}$$

Comment: @andeslisk This might be how the question should have been written, but at least in the form the OP posted, it is written as asking for the minimum temperature at which the reaction is spontaneous, which is a poorly posed question. They either needed to write the question as "find the equilibrium temperature" or "find the *max* temperature such that the reaction is spontaneous".

Comment: @Tyberius I agree that the problem could formulated more clearly. I've seen problems like this when the student was supposed to deduce what exactly is being asked by analyzing what data values are given. Not exactly fair, but the tasks like this also check attentiveness and knowledge of how to apply formulas on-the-fly.